# Openstack Image create fails "ConflictException: 409: Client Error for url: https://x.x.x.x:9292/v2/images/8f78f59e-0b60-477e-aec6-810af4646c69/file

Tags: openstack-glance

I just upgraded from OSA-Rocky to OSA-Stein and everything seems to work fine except when I try and upload an image via the python-openstackclient CLI.  We are running ceph nautilus as our storage.  Running the --debug option on the command gives the following:

###Cut majority of debug messages###

```
Starting new HTTPS connection (2): xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292
[>                             ] 1%https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292 "PUT /v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file HTTP/1.1" 409 79
RESP: [409] Connection: close Content-Length: 79 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 x-openstack-request-id: req-bf01af04-aa24-4ba6-bf93-7f909f442f37
RESP BODY: Omitted, Content-Type is set to text/plain; charset=UTF-8. Only application/json responses have their bodies logged.
PUT call to image for https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file used request id req-bf01af04-aa24-4ba6-bf93-7f909f442f37
Deleting failed upload of image ubuntu-server-20.04-focal
REQ: curl -g -i --insecure -X DELETE https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5 -H "User-Agent: openstacksdk/0.59.0 keystoneauth1/4.4.0 python-requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.6.8" -H "X-Auth-Token: {SHA256}7413f5abcbdc45993c0b64c560665f198387e1d3a4fa58549b55ba12dc25d03a"
Resetting dropped connection: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292 "DELETE /v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5 HTTP/1.1" 204 0
RESP: [204] Connection: close Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 x-openstack-request-id: req-631ee055-77ce-4b6a-8374-d53e3ab0e984
RESP BODY: Omitted, Content-Type is set to text/html; charset=UTF-8. Only application/json responses have their bodies logged.
DELETE call to image for https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5 used request id req-631ee055-77ce-4b6a-8374-d53e3ab0e984
Image creation failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/image/v2/_proxy.py", line 235, in _upload_image
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/image/v2/_proxy.py", line 293, in _upload_image_put
    exceptions.raise_from_response(response)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/exceptions.py", line 238, in raise_from_response
    http_status=http_status, request_id=request_id
openstack.exceptions.ConflictException: ConflictException: 409: Client Error for url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file, Conflict
ConflictException: 409: Client Error for url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file, Conflict
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 407, in run_subcommand
    result = cmd.run(parsed_args)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osc_lib/command/command.py", line 39, in run
    return super(Command, self).run(parsed_args)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cliff/display.py", line 115, in run
    column_names, data = self.take_action(parsed_args)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstackclient/image/v2/image.py", line 502, in take_action
    image = image_client.create_image(**kwargs)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/image/_base_proxy.py", line 213, in create_image
    **image_kwargs)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/image/v2/_proxy.py", line 235, in _upload_image
    **kwargs)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/image/v2/_proxy.py", line 293, in _upload_image_put
    exceptions.raise_from_response(response)
  File "/home/rkruck/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack/exceptions.py", line 238, in raise_from_response
    http_status=http_status, request_id=request_id
openstack.exceptions.ConflictException: ConflictException: 409: Client Error for url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file, Conflict
clean_up CreateImage: ConflictException: 409: Client Error for url: https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292/v2/images/395b1140-c0e3-48a9-872e-8b535cb237e5/file, Conflict
END return value: 1
```

Happy to provide anything else as I am stuck trying to get past this.  If I log into Horizon I do see an attempt to save the image, so I don't feel it is an authentication/access issue.

Comment: The problem is not on your side. Please go to server on https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9292 and find in logs what is reason of conflict.

Comment: I understand this is on the server side.  The logs are not telling me anything about a conflict.  At least not in the glance-api log.

Comment: In this cases i'll create simulation and use step debugger in visual studio to go line by line of code to understand its secrets. It take some time but it is only way when no one and nothing to be helpful (like me right now) I wish best luck to you.

Comment: thanks @Cybervitexus it is giving me a new direction to look into.